# Drive from Detroit MI to Pigeon Forge, Tenn. - Is it scary?

Tags: driving, road-trips, mountains

I want to drive to pigeon forge with my family and I see that going from where I am to pigeon forge is a good 8 hour drive.  I've driven a lot through Michigan, Ohio, and Illinois but not further down.  I'm curious to know is the drive to Tennessee scary in terms of a lot of steep hills, mountainous area, and wind?

I ask because I do get a little nervous with roads that are steep and just want to be sure this is something I could complete without having some sort of panic attack.  I plan to definitely rest stopping for food, etc. with my family.  The cost of air travel, rental car is so high right now that I could save a lot of money plus spend time with my family seeing the nice landscape.

Has anyone driven to Tennessee specifically that area and thought to themselves that was a mistake or am I making a big deal about nothing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can't know what scares you, but I can say that if you stick to the interstate highway system, those roads have [maximum grade of a 6%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstate_Highway_standards#Standards) in mountainous areas, and 4% in general.  These are not steep roads.

But from looking on google the only places you are likely to experience mountains are around Knoxville TN.  But even then I-75 winds it's way through various valleys.

As for winds, that is more likely to be a weather related aspect that is going depend on when you actually travel.  So while it may be sunny and calm now, you could experience a tornado next week (but highly unlikely).

If you have a modern car I recommend using lane assist when driving on the interstates.  I've used mine in very windy crosswinds and it really does help in keeping the car on the road.

Comment: I can assume you mean not to dread it then?

Comment: @JonH If you are happy driving on interstates, then I don't believe you should dread it for the reasons you were concerned about.

Comment: thanks I ended up having no issues except coming back I made a mistake leaving late and the highways in ohio dont have a lot of light!!!!